# Calling PHP JSON data results from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to obtain PHP data from my Javascript code. This is meant to be shown in the `dayta` div id. What I end up getting instead is `undefined` instead of the desired result (which in this instance is the `firstname` in my JSON file). I am not sure why this is happening.

My **JavaScript** code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
            var dayta = document.getElementById('datadisplay');
                dayta.innerHTML = http.response.firstname;
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", "myphpfile.php", true);
    http.send();
}
```

My **PHP** code (`myphpfile.php`):

```
<?php   
    $content = file_get_contents('somejsonfile.json');
    print_r($content);
    $dbcon->close();
?>
```

The PHP code included is only a portion of my code, but it contains all the parts relevant to my problem.

`$content` outputs a JSON file, as that is what it is pointed to. If I echo `$content` I am able to verify that the content is streamed out as intended.

Thus, the problem is most likely with my JavaScript code. But I cannot identify specifically what is wrong.

My **JSON** file (`somejsonfile.json`):

```
{"firstname": "Ki ki ki ma ma ma"}
```

I understand that the most obvious way to approach this specific example is to simply have the JavaScript file reach the JSON file. However, since I'm trying to secure the path of my JSON file in my production code I am trying out this method.

Comment: try `echo $content` instead of print_r

Comment: you should first always just try to print the result into the console, like: `console.log(http.responseText)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you get a JSON response by using `JSON.parse`. Here's a quick solution. I have tried it and it works great!

```
window.onload = function(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
            var dayta = document.getElementById('datadisplay');
            var data = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
            dayta.innerHTML = data.firstname;
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", "myphpfile.php", true);
    http.send();
}
```

Comment: I've tried parsing before, and just like what happened before, I end up with no result, and a console error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.http.onreadystatechange (infocall.js:6)` with line-6 being the `data = JSON.parse(http.responseText)` let me know if this is completely unrelated to what should be happening with my code.

Comment: @JasonChen Can you please copy and paste my code and let me know what you get?. I don't get any errors at all.

Comment: Nvm. an unrelated error on my end. Code works great!

Comment: @JasonChen Glad, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

pls check this code;

```
    <?php   
        $content = file_get_contents('somejsonfile.json');
        print_r(json_decode($content));
    ?>
```

if you see array truly then,

```
<?php   
    $content = file_get_contents('somejsonfile.json');
    echo(json_encode($content));
?>
```

if you want to query in json file, you can use json_decode function to convert array and push or remove array item and then json_encode.